# Google Tag Manager (and Analytics) SSL name mismatch

Tags: javascript, ssl, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In IE9, I'm getting the message 'Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors.'

My website is on https and I have narrowed the cause of this message down to two items. A reference to Google Analytics (GA) and Google Tag Manager (GTM).

- Google Analytics asks that you reference the url www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js, if I change this to ssl.google-analytics.com/analytics.js this resolves the issue for GA.
- GTM asks that i reference the url www.googletagmanager.com and I'm not sure if there is something I can change that to in order to prevent the message.

This site is currently on a development server and I'm also not sure that these same messages would apply to customers once in production.  The company sets a lot of custom security settings on our browser.

Any help would be much apprciated.

Below is the code snippet I'm using. I've changed a value to all X's.  I have also uploaded  a screenshot of what happens when I go directly to the url https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=

```
<script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
    'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
}); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
```

[image]

Comment: both ga and gtm tracking codes should detect HTTPS pages and use HTTPS as well. Can you share the snippet you use for GTM?

Comment: This turned out to be a restriction set on our internal network. I requested that these urls be let through and this resolved our issue.

Comment: I hope it didn't take you that long to figure it out.

Comment: @Matt what was your issue? What restriction did you remove in your internal network. We are also facing this issue in some locations.